# SOCIALENGINE - how to make search form remember last selection?

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I am running a socialengine site(which sits on Zend) and the search form reset every time a user get to another page.

Anyone know if there is a way to save the last selection on the search form for each field?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies, session or database to store last search params by member depending on how long you want to remember last member's search.